# Getting the right behaviour of Excel's PERCENTRANK.EXC on mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, excel-formula, percentile

I would like to replicate Excel's PERECENTRANK.EXC() functionality and behaviour on SQL.

Sample Data set:

[image]

From what I understand from PERCENTRANK.EXC(), it excludes the first and last value of the array.

However in SQL, I can't seem to find a way to replicate this, as PERCENT_RANK() in SQL seem to always give a value of 0 and 1 to the minimum and maximum values, thus deviating from what PERCENTRANK.EXC() in Excel does:

[image]

In SQL, this is how I tried to script it:

```
SELECT 
    market,
    campaign_coount,
    revenue,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY market ORDER BY revenue) as percentile
FROM data_table
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 3 DESC
```

Is there some variable input or some other RANK methods in SQL that I can use to mimic Excel's PERCENTRANK.EXC() function completely?

Edit: Ignoring trying to replicate the Excel's function; how do I write the query in SQL with PERCENT_RANK() such that it takes the value, but the array is excluding the first and last value when grouped by Market?

Thanks!

Comment: By asking for an excel equivalent you lose contributors who don't have excel , you should consider describing what you want in English and provide sample data as text

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the feedback. What I wanted was literally shown, excluding the first and last value of the array, and that percentile value of the first few values are also shown in the first screen shot. I'll try to be clearer